# Show Hide div & close with fadein fadeout on focus input

Tags: jquery

Hi i am using this code to show hide div on input focus

here is html please have a look @[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RU4kC/) also

```
<div id="divone">
    <input class="url_field" />
</div>
<div id="first" class="content">
    First
    <input class="close" type="button" value="X"/>
</div>
<div id="last" class="content">
    Last
    <input class="close" type="button" value="X"/>
</div>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".url_field").focus(function() {
        $(this).next(".content").fadeout('slow').css('display', 'inline');
    });

    $('.url_field').focus(function() {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#' + this.rel + '').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('.content input.close').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

please help me, its not working

Comment: Use 'e' in your fadeout, no? )

Comment: there is no element '.showdiv'

Comment: Use your browser's-javascript console to see the errors. There are many...

Comment: Its `fadeout('slow')` not `fadout('slow')`

Comment: i edited please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/RU4kC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.url_field').focus(function() {
        //$(this).next(".showdiv").fadout('slow').css('display', 'inline');  not sure what this does so commented it out
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show(); // you also don't have a rel on the input so this won't do anything
        return false;
    });

    $('.content input.close').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

also you probably want your css to start with display block unless you are starting them hidden and then showing them - but then you need to add rel="last" or rel="first" to your input

Comment: a little issue, it's working well here http://jsfiddle.net/RU4kC/11/ but here http://beurl.in it show hide div only one time.